# Why are directories sometimes listed explicitly in ZIP files?

Tags: zip

While building an application that extracts ZIP files I noticed that sometimes ZIP files explicitly contain entries for the directories and sometimes not. Given for example the following structure

```
folder1/
└── file1
```

I find files that give the following different outputs when listing the contents via `unzip -lv file.zip`:

```
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       5  Stored        5   0% 2023-04-20 13:54 3bb935c6  folder1/file1
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       5                5   0%                            1 file
```

```
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2023-04-20 13:54 00000000  folder1/
       5  Stored        5   0% 2023-04-20 13:54 3bb935c6  folder1/file1
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       5                5   0%                            2 files
```

Note the explicitly stated folder in the second one.

What is the standard here? Do programs usually make assumptions how this is handled? Is one of the two advantageous?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The standard](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) doesn’t specify this, but common practice is to store directories as separate entries, so that directory metadata can also be stored.

Since ZIP files *without* separate directory entries are valid, programs shouldn’t make assumptions about them either way.

(With Info-Zip `zip`, the `-D` flag skips storing directory entries.)